# Silent Java update check

Tags: windows, java, powershell, vbscript, automatic-update

How to have automatic Java updates without **jusched.exe** process running all the time in the background and with control when a check for the update should occur?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what's being asked here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assumptions:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Java 32-bit

---

Disable Java Automatic Updates: [Change Java Update options](https://superuser.com/a/443678/143218).

---

Create **java_check_update.ps1** PowerShell script with following content:

```
$currVer = Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" -name "CurrentVersion"

if (!$currVer.'CurrentVersion') {
    Exit
}

$famVerStr = ('Java' + $currVer.'CurrentVersion'.Split(".")[1] + 'FamilyVersion')
$famVer = Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" -name $famVerStr

if (!$famVer.$famVerStr) {
    Exit
}

$java_version = $famVer.$famVerStr

$url = "http://javadl-esd.sun.com/update/" + $currVer.'CurrentVersion' + ".0/map-" + $currVer.'CurrentVersion' + ".0.xml"

$c = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$xml = $c.DownloadString($url)

$p = [xml]$xml
$n = $p.SelectSingleNode('java-update-map/mapping[version="' + $java_version + '"]')

if ($n) {
    #update available
    cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Java\Java Update\jucheck.exe"
}
```

---

Create **java_check_update.vbs** VBScript with following content:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File ""PATH_TO_POWERSHELL_SCRIPT""", 0
```

**PATH_TO_POWERSHELL_SCRIPT** for example: `D:\Scripts\java_check_update.ps1`

---

Add new task in Task Scheduler to run script **java_check_update.vbs** (full path to file) every day, week or month.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this program [auto java updater](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autojavaupdater/). Schedule it and let it run in the background and it will do everything automaticly.